# Parabola/Analytic Geometry - $y=kx+5$ intersects for all values of $k$ with parabola $y=x^2+2$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, analytic-geometry, quadratics

The question states:

Show that the line $y=kx+5$ intersects with the 
Parabola $y=kx+2$ for all values of k.

I thought this would be similar to the other problems where I use the discriminant but the answer ends up not being real... ?

I set them equal to each other,

$x^2+2=kx+5$

$x^2-kx-3=0$

$Δ=κ^2-4(-3)(1)$

Then I set this to 0 to find intersection, but it doesn't have a real intersection.

$k^2+12=0$

Any ideas?

Comment: Evidently $k^2+12>0$ for every $k$. This tells us that the equation $x^2+2=kx+5$ has solutions for every $k$. Solutions correspond with intersections of the parabola (LHS) and the line (RHS), so...

Comment: You wrote about a Parabola with equation $y=kx+2,$ did you mean $y=x^2+2$ which you wrote in the next line?

Comment: Why are you setting the discriminant to zero? The equation has real solutions when $\Delta\ge0$.